# Pycharm. 'Process finished with exit code 0' . No output in after running the code

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to PyCharm and I was testing out this code I saw online but when I tried running it, the output never showed as I had expected. I am current using the community version of PyCharm.

I researched and tried some of the resolutions posted by other users but still the output was the same. I feel completely lost can someone help:)

I have attached a screenshot of the configuration settings. [image]

Comment: can you show us the code, i think the problem is not with pycharm it self

Comment: [edit] your post and add your code into it

Comment: Most likely you do not have any print statements. Your code ran without any issues so it exited after doing all it's work. Unless you share some code we cannot help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.